# How to run a production build of my react app locally?

Tags: reactjs, yarnpkg, production

My package.json has the following script:

```
"build": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'"
```

When I run `yarn build` I get the following error:

`sh: .env.: No such file or directory`

The .env file is in the top level of my project directory as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: But the `.env.` file is not ( see trailing dot ), as `REACT_APP_ENV` is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy or rename `.env.foo` to `.env.foo.sh` and add `export` at the beginning of each line, like this:

```sh
export REACT_APP_HEADER_COLOR="#f66"
```

Source this new shellscript instead of the old env file:

```
"sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}.sh; react-scripts build'"
```

Now the variables will be successfully passed down to the build process, for it to use.

### Why?

That is just how shells work.  An environment variable loaded into the current shell (with `source` or `.` or assignment) is only passed down to the child, if it is exported:

```sh
$ FOO=foo
$ sh -c 'echo $FOO'

$ export FOO=foo
$ sh -c 'echo $FOO'
foo
```

Note that these one-line shortcuts also export automatically/implicitly:

```sh
$ BAR=bar sh -c 'echo $BAR'
bar
$ env BAR=baz sh -c 'echo $BAR'
baz
```

(I suspect this hidden behaviour is a frequent source of confusion.)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the `NODE_ENV` variable, it gives you the environment mode.

I don't know if you're using `create-react-app`, but if you are (once you have built your app), you can use `serve` to run the production version:

`$ npm install -g serve`

`$ serve -s build`